# Icon for "title" and "subtitle"

Tags: website-design, icons, copywriting, labels

I am creating a template for TV programme details. For each programme, I have a title and a subtitle. Instead of writing "Title" and "Subtitle" in full, I was thinking of using an icon.

What icon would you suggest for "Title" and "Subtitle"?

Comment: Since what is being asked is for icons to *replace* the words, I'm not sure it's a good idea. I can't think of anything that could be clearer than the words themselves - they're not exactly long, and they are perfectly descriptive.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The best option is to use "Title" and "Subtitle".

Images as icons work when they are either **standard** (e.g. pause, home, or refresh) or **concrete** terms (e.g. person, global, or phone).  When they are both non-standard and abstract, text is the least confusing choice.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of icons, use different text sizes. Title should be bigger (and maybe bold) than subtitle. And you can give subtitle less contrast (use grey instead of white on a black background).

Answer (score 2):

Is this for data input or data retrieval/display? If for input, I agree with the others...just use the actual text. If for display, I don't think you need text nor icons...as the content is rather self Explanatory:

```
M*A*S*H
Klinger Does Something Silly
Episode 24, 1982
```